# File Upload Jersey Multipart Not Working in MULE 3.5.0

Tags: jersey, mule, esb

I have tried to create a file upload functionality using this [this example](http://www.javaroots.com/2013/05/createfileuploadmulejerseyrest.html). But this example is not working in mule 3.5.0 giving 400 BAD REQUEST error . please note that i have included jersey-multipart-1.6 and mimepull-1.6 jars in my build path .Here is the code

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "D://" + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

No error or exception are printed on mule side . i think the request is not even reaching to component . This code is working in mule 3.4 .

please help me on this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mule 3.5 the default message factory for the http transport changed to HttpMultipartMuleMessageFactory. In Mule 3.4 this was HttpMuleMessageFactory.

**Solution:**

Define a http connector and override the messageFactory as follows:

```
<http:connector name="http">
    <service-overrides messageFactory="org.mule.transport.http.HttpMuleMessageFactory" />
</http:connector>
```

Refer to this connector from your http inbound endpoint.

Comment: where do we add these things in Grails ?